# How to strip sub-directories from path using shell

Tags: linux, shell, sed, makefile

In a make file i want to strip some sub-directories from a path given in a variable. I figure i can use `$(shell ...)` to do it, so a `sed` one-liner or similar would do the trick i think. Any suitable `make` technique would do though.

The path contained in the variable typically looks like:

```
/repo/myrepo/products/foo/prod1/test/gtest/bin/XXX
```

or

```
/repo/myrepo/products/cool_products/bar/prod2/test/gtest/bin
```

And i want to strip everything after `prod1` and `prod2` above, giving the results:

```
/repo/myrepo/products/foo/prod1
/repo/myrepo/products/cool_products/bar/prod2
```

In other words, strip all directories starting with `test/gtest` which i can assume is in all the paths i will be applying this to. I have not been able to figure out a clean way to strip a different number of sub-directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's#/test/gtest.*##g'
```

This will remove everything from `/test/gtest` to the end.

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ echo "/repo/myrepo/products/foo/prod1/test/gtest/bin/XXX" | sed 's#/test/gtest.*##g'
/repo/myrepo/products/foo/prod1
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Will accept in 7 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, if you want to do it with functions internal to GNU make instead of invoking a separate program via `$(shell ...)`, would be something like:

```
FULL_PATH = /repo/myrepo/products/foo/prod1/test/gtest/bin/XXX

STRIPPED_PATH := $(firstword $(subst /test/gtest, ,$(FULL_PATH)))
```

Basically this says "take `$(FULL_PATH)` and first replace the string `/test/gtest` with a space character everywhere it appears in the string, then return the first word of the resulting string".